# Change ALL chart series colors

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

Is it possible to change the color of every series in a chart to the same thing WITHOUT LOOPING through each individual series?

This doesn't work:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(155, 200, 27)
```

Comment: What did you find after doing your research?

Comment: @braX I can do it fine looping through each series, but i have absolutely no idea how to refer to all the series in one go and make the color change, I've updated the question to reflect that

Comment: Whats wrong WITH LOOPING ?

Comment: @TimWilliams just assumed looping might be slower than setting a color all in one go, considering it's all the same color, and it would also make for neater code not having the loop :)

Comment: I think in this case you have to loop.  If it's a common thing you need to do then you can always factor it out into a separate Sub.

Comment: @TimWilliams ah thanks, figured it might not be a doable thing, the best option then would be to do as you have suggested and pull it out into a separate sub

Comment: Another way to think about this - is it possible to change the color of every series *manually*? If not, most likely not possible either with a VBA one-liner.

Comment: If a chart has more than one series, then they will by default have different colours. The series colours cannot be changed for all series in a chart in one command, VBA or not. If you want to have all series in the same colour, maybe you're using the wrong chart. What kind of chart do you have in mind? Why not create a chart that has only one series? Then you don't need to edit individual series colours.